# Broadcast Apple Push Notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification, ipod-touch

Is it possible to **broadcast** push notifications without services like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly, but you need to implement the entire infrastructure on your own.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

Edit: You're emphasizing "broadcast" in your question. Urban Airship doesn't do anything special, other than tracking every single device token that has been registered in the lifetime of the application, as well as tracking those tokens which Apple has told it to turn off. The broadcast feature is just them utilizing all that data to send a batch of pushes.

It's all doable on your own, but it's a lot of work. This is why services like Urban Airship exist.

Comment: Thanks. I won't be able to track every single device token if it is required to doa  broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to set up the backend using [this](https://github.com/jpoz/APNS) and Rails.